# How to: C++ Program to make box of X's ?

Tags: c++

having some trouble with my assignment. The program's purpose is to ask user to enter width and length of the box made of X's, and create that, with no blanks. I'm not sure why my program is printing 4 X's when I input 5 for both length and width, and printing out only 3 rows, with 2 extra X's for the bottom row.

```
Input: Width: 5, Length: 5
Output:
XXXX
XXXX
XXXXXXX
Desired Output: 
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

Here's my program so far, any advice would be very much appreciated!

```
//Print a box of X's

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
int length, width;
char character;

cout << "Please enter the length.";
cin >> length;


while (length < 0 || length > 25)
{
    cout << "Invalid input. Try again." << endl;
    cin >> length;
}


cout << "Please enter the width.";
cin >> width;   
while (width < 0 || width > 25)
{
    cout << "Invalid input. Try again." << endl;

    cin >> width;
}
character = 'X';
for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) //top 
    cout << character;
cout << endl;

for (int i = 1; i < width; ++i) //bottom
    cout << character;
cout << endl;

for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) //left and right
    cout << character;
for (int k = 1; k < width; k++)
    cout << character;
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Usually, loops in C and C++ start at zero, such as `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)`

Comment: You don't need special treatment for top and bottom in this version. (You would if drawing a hollow box)

Comment: Yeah I thought about it and realized 0 made the program much smoother. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 3):

Try to write two nested for loops it's really easy you can use length and width for example like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        cout << 'X';
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Definitely helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The proper and efficient way to make a box of X's in C can be done by nesting two for loops, one for the length and one for the width.

This way, the program simply makes a line of some length, as many times as you wish making the width.

Instead of

```html
for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) //top 
    cout << character;
cout << endl;

for (int i = 1; i < width; ++i) //bottom
    cout << character;
cout << endl;

for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) //left and right
    cout << character;
for (int k = 1; k < width; k++)
    cout << character;
```

You can simply put (note that I started at 0, and not 1)

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    cout << "X"
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Sweet! I appreciate the help, definitely made my coding look much neater.